# How to ensure emails are validated according to the new TLD

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am using spring validation:

```
@NotNull
@Size(max = 128, min = 6)
@Email
private String username;
```

But I want to ensure that the new TLDs are respected. Does spring even look at the email domain TLDs and ensure they are adhered to?

Just to give an example: I want the following to validate: joe@emperor.clothing

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you after? What do you mean with:

> But I want to ensure that the new TLDs are respected

`@Email` is  Hibernate Validator provided Bean Validation constraint which will verify whether a given email adheres syntactically [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). It does so via a regular expression.

The javadocs of `EmailValidator` says:

> The specification of a valid email can be found in RFC 2822 and one
>   can come up with a regular expression matching all valid email
>   addresses as per specification. However, as this article discusses it
>   is not necessarily practical to implement a 100% compliant email
>   validator. This implementation is a trade-off trying to match most
>   email while ignoring for example emails with double quotes or
>   comments.

This also means, that there is no internet connection established to for example verify whether a top level domain actually exists (in case that is what you mean).